# fedora 23 update kills XFS-how to install new xfsprogs?

Tags: fedora, xfs

I've been running 4.4.5 and it's been stable. I got the update prompt from Gnome Software and figured WTF I'll run it on reboot. I came back into the room to Fedora in emergency mode prompting for root creds. the error in dmesg gives me an RIP on XFS.

Quick google search shows a known bug which can be resolved with the latest version of xfsprogs and running xfs_repair. so my question is basically how do I get the patched version of xfsprogs onto the system to be able to repair the volume? This is an EFI installation and standard partitions, not LVM. All partitions (except EFI) are XFS. No other kernels will get me into a working system. 4.4.5 gets me to emergency mode, 4.3.x gets me into another non-single user mode.

[image]

https://bodhi.fedoraproject.org/updates/FEDORA-2016-462b3247db

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody had any help here, I burned the current Live disc, which had a newer kernel and the patched version of xfsprogs. From the live disc, I was able to run xfs_repair and resolve the issues. this still failed to emergency mode, but I was able to then run xfs_repair from the native install, which allowed me to get back into the system.